# Existence of a continuous real-valued function in two real variables

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Does there exist a continuous function $F:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $D(F)=\mathbb{R}^{2}$, that is $|F(x,y)|<+\infty$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$, such that 
$$\lim_{|x-y|\to 0} F(x,y)=+\infty\;?$$

Comment: The condition $|F(x,y)|<\infty$ is superfluous as we are talking about functions $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

No. If this was true, you would have in particular $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}F(x,y)=+\infty$.

But you assumed that $F$ is continuous. In particular, it is continuous at $(0,0)$ so the latter limit is equal to $F(0,0)$ and it is finite.